# bootstrap mobile view is not working properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: desktop viewenter code here]working with Bootstrap 4 and I have following bootstrap codes with external css file in the html view,

```
<div class="jumbotron rounded-0">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="{{asset('images/flowler.jpg')}}" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

External css

```
.rounded-circle{
    vertical-align: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: -50px;
    
  }
```

but in mobile view in the browser above images not displaying properly. it is not in the correct position. how could I fix this problem?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuQXa.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/daggf.png`enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daggf.png%60enter) code[image: mobile view] here`

Comment: If you can put a picture of the page. But I think your problem will be solved by putting `col-xs-4`.

Comment: @MehranGharzi putting col-xs-4 is not sucess here. anyway I have added image when see mobile view

Comment: If the image is not correct only on the mobile, use the `col-xs-4` class next to `col-md-4`. How should the image be displayed?

Comment: still same problem here

Comment: Where should the image be displayed?

Comment: in the jumbotron when desktop and mobile views.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gharzim/myqwv6th/
Where should the image be displayed?

Comment: in the middle of the left corner of the jumbotrone

Answer (score 0):

You specify the value `left: -100%;` You move the image out of the page

```css
  .rounded-circle{
    vertical-align: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

  <div class="jumbotron rounded-0">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://www.ivertech.com/Articles/Images/KoalaBear200x200.jpg" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```